# Visual Studio Code go to type definition in Verilog

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to see if there is anyway we can enable go to type definition for System Verilog classes in Visual Studio Code. Currently, when I hover over it, I don't see any definition. Thanks for the help in advance.

I tried to see if there are any settings to enable that and couldn't find anything. It seems we need to add language support to enable that, but not sure how we do that.

Answer (score 0):

To install a language support, go to Extensions (click the button on the sidebar) and type 'verilog' in the search field. You will get a list of available extensions. Click on each one to get its description.

[image]
If there is any that suits your needs, click the blue "Install" button.

Answer (score 0):

svlangserver is the only vs code extension that I have found with this functionality. It will index your workspace on boot, you can monitor this in the terminal output. I use verilator as the linter which also works well.